# Как сделать скриншот рабочего стола без панели Пуск?

Tags: delphi, скриншот

Как можно получить скриншот только рабочего стола со значками, то есть чтобы в скриншот не попали окна панель задач, там где *пуск*, а только рабочий стол со значками?

Answer (score 4):

Попробуйте:

```
var
  DesktopBitmap: TBitmap;    
begin    
  DesktopBitmap.GetDC(GetDesktopWindow);
```

Подробней посмотрите здесь: [Screen Shuffling with Delphi](http://delphi.about.com/od/graphics/l/aa082801a.htm).

Comment: Пишет неизвестный индификатор GetDC

Comment: С помощью GetDC окна всё равно наложатся на рисунок.

Comment: Смысл заключается в получении хендла рабочего стола.

Comment: И смысл?! Вот получу я хендл, вот скопирую картинку с хендла, но те окна, которые было поверх рабочего стола всё равно будут!

Comment: Вы ошибаетесь, поверхность останется поверхностью, единственное, что может случиться, Вы получите только изображение обоев рабочего стола, т.к. рабочий стол состоит из нескольких поверхностей(окон), возможно надо будет получить дочернюю(со значками) и совместить. Если Вам необходимо решение проблемы то попробуйте идти в этом направлении.

Comment: Ладно, попробую, но компилятор пишет неизвестный индификатор GetDC. Он не знает что такое GetDC!

Comment: Компилятор знает, что такое GetDC, просто GetDC - это winapi функция. Она не относится к классу TBitMap.  
правильно будет просто "GetDC(GetDesktopWindow);", предварительно добавив "windows" в раздел uses.

А куда функция будет возвращать значение - выбирайте сами.

Answer (score 3):

Можно сделать скриншот любого окна, используя **bitblt**. Эта функция, думаю, то, что вам необходимо. Скриншот рабочего стола можно сделать так:

```
...
var
  bmp:Tbitmap;
...
begin
  bmp := TbitMap.Create;
  bmp.Width := screen.Width;
  bmp.Height := screen.Height;
  bitblt(bmp.canvas.Handle, 0, 0, screen.Width, screen.Height, getdc(FindWindow('ProgMan', nil)), 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
```

Comment: Пробовал, всё равно в изображение попадают другие окна!

Comment: Не могут попадать! FindWindow('ProgMan', nil) - это окно рабочего стола. Какая у вас версия windows?

Comment: Windows XP!

Comment: Попробуйте тогда использовать такой идентификатор:

    FindWindow('Progman', 'Program Manager');